# How to pass data into another page using express node js

Tags: node.js, express

Here is my code. When it is executing it shows some errors

```
var express = Express();
express.post('/start', async function (req, res) {
 let data  = req.body.name;
 console.log(data);
 var x = {name : data};
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/view', 'play.html', x));
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide the error you are getting? This will make it easier for us to troubleshoot and help you.

Comment: '(node:18812) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Path must be a string. Received { name: 'kkrtkert' }
    at assertPath (path.js:28:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:489:7)'. 
**This is the error**

Comment: `res.sendFile()` does not accept arguments like your `x`.  Perhaps you meant to be using `res.render()`?   And, you're also mistakenly passing `x` to `path.join()`.

Comment: Try `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/view', 'play.html'), {data: x});`

Comment: I also used res.render('play',x); .But it also shows an error like this.. UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module 'html'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)

Comment: To use `res.render()` you have to install and register a view engine (which is how you get template-type functionality with Express).  It's unclear what you're trying to do and it appears you haven't really studied the express documentation much to find examples of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to use `ejs` templating langague (but you can choose any other).

- install ejs (npm install ejs)
- set up views folder in your root directory `/views`

In your application

```
const app = require('express');

// set ejs as a view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.post('/start', (req, res) => {
  const name = req.body.name;

  // render your play.ejs file which is located in views
  // /views/play.ejs
  // second parameter is an object that will be accessible in your view
  res.render('play', { name });
});
```

display data in your view using `<%= %>` syntax

`/views/play.ejs`

```
<p><%= name %></p>
```

Answer (score -2):

You are passing the 'x' variable into the path.join method which is causing the error.

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/view', 'play.html', x));
```

x is an object and the path.join method only accepts strings.

Comment: so how to convert X into a string..?

Comment: Why are you passing x into path in the first place it does not make any sense.